# Isolating monkey patches in a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, monkeypatching

I've noticed that a few ruby gems that I use ship with a folder named `ext` or `core_ext` which contains a set of monkey patches to the core library that is used in their code. However, when I `require` those gems I get those monkey patches as well.

Is it possible for gem authors or for gem users to isolate those monkey patches such that they are only visible in the Modules that the gem defines/exports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be possible until refinements are implemented, see [Shugo Maeda's proposal](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4085).

Comment: Isn't what is being done in this file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb monkey patching?

It opens up the core String class and adds methods.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking of adding a method vs modifying existing method, but both are considered monkey patches. Edited my answer.